# Unable to print picture after request

Tags: php, html, mysql

What´s is wrong on this sentence?

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_id'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_role'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_passw'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_init'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['c_name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_mail'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'.'<img href="'. $row['u_pic'] . '" width=45 height=45></img>'.'</td>';`    
}
```

I´m able to print all fields after query but for last one is not possible, I got on db saved the url for the picture with this format

http://localhost/Pics/st.gif dbfield as varchar

If I inspect the component in the browser I can see it was properly selected by mysql but there is not print on the screen.

Any comment? Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the value of `$row['u_pic']`?

Comment: just view your html-sourcecode and go from there.

Comment: http://localhost/Pics/st.gif

Comment: `href`? maybe you mean `src`, image tags use source attributes, hrefs are for anchor tags

Comment: I tryed with both scr adn href, but no result

Comment: What is the path of the saved picture?

Comment: use src and also remove the `</img>` closing tag, that is not needed.

Comment: on the path I test with full url  http://localhost/Pics/picture name and ../../folder/picture.gif

Comment: If I use Chrome component inspector I can see that on each row there is the right url of each picture but I do not see the picture phisically just an square around the place is suppose to be.

Comment: Do you save the path in your database?

Comment: Yes path is on db, and it is right if I follow the path

Comment: Try using another browser and tell us if that works.

Comment: This is an example only: `src="localhost/public/images/image.jpg"`. The path of this is `../public/images/`

Comment: Hi Björn, I test it wit Explore with same results.

Comment: Hi aldrin27, I set noe the path on db like you indicated ..//Pics/picture.png

Comment: But dosent works, the picture looks to be there so I assume the query is working and html as well because Chrome inspector tell me that picure is there but for any reason it is not shown, really a mistery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For images you'll have to use:

```
<img src="url">
```

Comment: Please could you explain your comment? I set it now as scr and not as href , what do oyu mean?

Comment: Href links to something. For example href is used in links. src mens source, so it imports something.

Comment: Yes I changed this and now looks like this : echo '<td>'.'<img scr="'. $row['u_pic'] . '" width=45 height=45></img>'.'</td>'; not still not shonw on the table, I just have an square border as if the picture were there but not picture inside the square.

Comment: You are using scr. Please use src.

Comment: Oh my god!!!!, you are absoultelly righ, it solved automatically the problem, it was just a gramatical error.......

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '<td><img src="'. $row['u_pic'] . '" width=45 height=45></img></td>';
```

Comment: No results with this Laila

Answer (score 0):

It should be in following way,

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_id'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_role'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_passw'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_init'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['c_name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_mail'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'.'<img src="'. $row['u_pic'] . '" width=45 height=45></img>'.'</td>'; 
}
```

Comment: Hi purushothan, sorry I do not follow you, where is the change proposed? It looks to be the same code I posted, could you explaim me where is the difference? Thanks

Comment: instead of html use src, and type this one  http://localhost/Pics/st.gif your browser window if you are getting image then above code will work. and at last line you need to remove ` mark.

Comment: http://localhost/Planning%20project/Pics/st.gif so I can not place on db the simbol %20?

Comment: then do like this str_replace(" ","%20",$row['u_pic']);

Comment: finally code will be like this
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_id'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_role'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_passw'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_init'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['c_name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['u_mail'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'.'<img src="'.  str_replace(" ","%20",$row['u_pic']) . '" width=45 height=45></img>'.'</td>'; 
}

Comment: Hi  purushotham I changed the folder name to simplify the code so now is localhost/PlanningProjects/Pics/(And here tehre are the pictures). So the line with problems looks like this but still not results: echo '<td>'.'<img scr="'. $row['u_pic'] . '" width=45 height=45></img>'.'</td>';

Comment: I know I´m getting the right picture for each row, if I use the Chrome inspector I can see the different files on the page code, but for any reason I just have a empty square without picture insde. I even disable the css file )(Bootstrap) thinking that somehting on the style is making the result worng but no way.

Comment: by typing  http://localhost/PlanningProjects/Pics/st.gif in your browser, what you are getting

Comment: is your $row['u_pic'] field is returning same http://localhost/PlanningProjects/Pics/st.gif?

Comment: Yes if I take the source page I see on each row the right picture path

Comment: I´m testing in two ways, in one field at db I got one picture like Pics/MA.png and in other like localhost/PlanningProject/Pics/st.gif but do not work in any case. db file tipe is varchar 50, is it ok?

Comment: It is solved..... no scr but src....... my basic mistake, thanks for oyur support.